# Angular testing with Jasmine can't compare html node

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am building directive tests in Angular using Jasmine. I have a small example test which looks like this:

```
it("should compare html node", inject( function ($compile, $rootScope) {
  var elm = angular.element('<input>');
  elm = $compile(elm)($scope);
  $scope.$digest();
  console.log('btn', elm); // output: '<input class="ng-scope">'
  expect(elm).toBe('<input class="ng-scope">');

  expect(elm[0]).toBe('<input class="ng-scope">'); // these also fail
  expect(elm.html()).toBe('<input class="ng-scope">'); // ""
}));
```

So I get the expected output to the console, but Jasmine complains with an error `Expected { length: 1, 0: HTMLNode } to be '<input class="ng-scope">'`

I have also tried using `elm[0]` which gives the same error and `elm.html()` but that just returns an empty string. How can I compare the HTML Node with the string correctly?

NB I know this is an unrealistic test, but I just want to demo my current issue.

Comment: maybe try elm[0].outerHTML

Comment: Wow! This actually works. I could find it documented in the API (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) though. If you want to make it into an answer I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So the elm is an `angular.element` which is a jqLite object. As you point out you can use elm[0] to get the actual dom element. Then you can access the html of the node by accessing the field `.outerHTML`. So our final solution is to use

```
elm[0].outerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing my Jasmine tests I would test the `element.html()` so I can then use jQuery to search for specific conditions such as

```
expect(element.html()).toContain($('input.ng-scope'));
```

I did go deeper and try to see about comparing HTMLNode to HTMLNode but I believe this is a limitation of Jasmine. You could try,

```
expect(element[0]).toEqual($.parseHTML('<input class="ng-scope">')[0])
```

But Jasmine gives back "Expected HTMLNode to equal HTMLNode". The best way to best it is to deconstruct the compiled HTML element as shown above with different test cases.

Comment: element.html() sometimes returns empty string, where elm[0].outerHTML returns HTML